# I would like to know why `while` in NetworkStream does not execute immediately and waits

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

I have a server program.
And there is also a client program.

The server was created using `TcpListener`, and the client was created using `TcpClient`.

After several experiments, `while` in the code below is not executed until `stream.write()` is executed in the client program.

Can you tell by what principle this is?

```cs
while (true) // That's no!
{
  Console.WriteLine("waiting connection...");

  TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
  Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

  data = null;

  NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

  int i;
  // This is while
  while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
  {
    data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
  }

  Console.WriteLine("This statement is only executed when stream.write() is executed.");

  client.Close();
}
```

Comment: `stream.Read()` is a blocking operation by default. That means execution will be suspended until there is some data available to be read, or an error (or exception) occurs. This is discussed in the documentation for [NetworkStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I didn't understand what Blocking mode was, but thanks to that, I understood.

Answer (score 0):

To which `while` are you referring, the outer or inner one?

Up to what point DOES the server execute before the client writes to the stream?
That should be easy to figure out with a few breakpoints.

`TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();` will block until a connection from the client is requested.

Comment: Oh, inner `while`. I know why outer `while` doesn't work. I edited the article a bit more.

Comment: So where does the server stop executing? It should stop at `AcceptTcpClient()` until a connection is initiated and then continue